# I can't get an SVG wrapped in a div to scale properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have the following HTML hierarchy:

```
div: flex 1 1 auto height=56px (modified by JS)
  div: grid 1fr
    svg with viewBox, width=100% height=100%
```

This correctly scales the svg to fit within the grid div as the top-level div's height gets changed by JS.
But when there's one more level of div in there, the svg disregards the parent scale and overflows the parents:

```
div: flex 1 1 auto height=56px (modified by JS)
  div: grid 1fr
    wrapper div ***PROBLEM***
      svg with viewBox, width=100% height=100%
```

I have a snippet below showing the behavior of the two cases. Unfortunately in my real app, I sometimes need that wrapper (it might be an `<a>` instead of a `<div>`, but that also shows the same problem). Can I somehow make that element not affect the SVG scaling algorithm?
I've reviewed [resize svg wrapped in div that is wrapped in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422304) but none of the solutions there help.
I'm looking for a pure HTML/CSS solution, since in my real code the JS resizing is happening in a framework.
I'm using recent Chrome btw.

Here's a snippet of both cases:

```js
function resizeElt(id, h) {
  const elt = document.getElementById(id)
  elt.style.height = h
}
let large = false
function resize(id) {
  large=!large
  resizeElt(id, large ? '100px' : '50px')
}
```

```css
.top {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.svg {
  margin: auto; /* center */
  display: block;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  column-gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
}
```

```html
<h3>
Show fit to width and height: SVG stays within bounds
</h3>
<button onclick="resize('top1')">
Resize container taller/shorter
</button>

<div id="top1" class="top">
<div class="inner1 grid">
<svg class="svg" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 20 10">
    <polygon fill=red stroke-width=0 points="0,10 20,10 10,0" />
    <polygon fill=green stroke-width=0 points="0,10 20,10 10,5" />
</svg>
</div>
</div>

<h3>
Example 2, SVG wrapped in div, doesn't scale properly:
</h3>
<button onclick="resize('top2')">
Resize taller/shorter
</button>

<div id="top2" class="top">
<div class="inner1 grid">
<div class="wrapper">
<svg class="svg" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 20 10">
    <polygon fill=red stroke-width=0 points="0,10 20,10 10,0" />
    <polygon fill=green stroke-width=0 points="0,10 20,10 10,5" />
</svg>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D: Snippet added.

Comment: Changing {display: grid} to {display: block} for '.grid' and setting .wrapper {height: 100%, width: 100%} solves the problem

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky unfortunately I do need the grid; this example is cut down from a larger case (the grid is a menu bar, and the SVG logo is one element of that.) Any other ideas? (I did try putting another div with `display:block` around the wrapper, but that doesn't help.)

Comment: Bigger question: how can you debug this kind of thing? Is there any way to see what the browser's sizing algorithm is doing? Or is there a spec where the behavior is laid out?

Answer (score 1):

Just added two rules to `.wrapper` and now it seems to work.

```
.wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```js
function resizeElt(id, h) {
  const elt = document.getElementById(id)
  elt.style.height = h
}
let large = false
function resize(id) {
  large=!large
  resizeElt(id, large ? '100px' : '50px')
}
```

```css
.top {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.svg {
  margin: auto; /* center */
  display: block;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  column-gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h3>
Show fit to width and height: SVG stays within bounds
</h3>
<button onclick="resize('top1')">
Resize container taller/shorter
</button>

<div id="top1" class="top">
<div class="inner1 grid">
<svg class="svg" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 20 10">
    <polygon fill=red stroke-width=0 points="0,10 20,10 10,0" />
    <polygon fill=green stroke-width=0 points="0,10 20,10 10,5" />
</svg>
</div>
</div>

<h3>
Example 2, SVG wrapped in div, <strike>doesn't</strike> scale properly:
</h3>
<button onclick="resize('top2')">
Resize taller/shorter
</button>

<div id="top2" class="top">
<div class="inner1 grid">
<div class="wrapper">
<svg class="svg" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 20 10">
    <polygon fill=red stroke-width=0 points="0,10 20,10 10,0" />
    <polygon fill=green stroke-width=0 points="0,10 20,10 10,5" />
</svg>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```